# Is it ok to announce I'm planning on placing a bounty?

Tags: discussion

I have a question on SO I'd like solved as soon as possible (me and everyone else). The moment a bounty is possible, I plan on setting one. However, I don't mind committing to a bounty right now, and if someone helps me before then, I'll set the bounty and hand it right on over.

Is it ok to finish my question with something like:

> I will reward a bounty of +100 to any user who helps solve my problem as soon as one become available.

Or does this go against the nature of the "wait 2 days before setting a bounty" mechanic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's simply noise.  Your question is where you ask your question, not where you post meta commentary about your question such as your plans for a bounty on your question.

At most you could post it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

### Sure.

I don't see any problem with announcing early that you plan to post a bounty, and I'm sure I've seen it done before on various SE sites. (None of them were SO, because I'm not on that site, but if you want an SO-specific answer, you should have asked on Meta.SO instead.)

That said, I'd probably suggest that you say it in a *comment* instead of in your question post. That way, you keep your question focused on its actual content, and you can easily remove the bounty 'pre-offer' once you actually start the bounty.